# Утечка, или что "держит" окно

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Создан проект, в нем есть куча разных окон, которые создаются и закрываются, однако память потихоньку выжерается, GC.Collect не помогает. Прочитал, что окно в памяти может держать подписка на события, однако перешерстить весь код и узнать что именно держит окно это мало говоря хардкор. Есть ли какие-нибудь методы отлова таких событий?

Comment: Конечно есть. В VS2015 уже встроен такой тулз, также есть DotMemory. Делаем снапшот памяти после закрытия окна, ищем класс окна в снапшоте и узнаем кто на него ссылку имеет. Да и вообще даст понять кто именно жрет память, может не окно вовсе.

Comment: @vitidev я так понимаю это запуск диагностики, рылся в нём недавно, но скорее всего из за неопытности не смог достичь дзена.

Comment: Это Diagnostic Tools, который при запуске дебага справа появляется и показывает инфу (не знаю в каких редакциях студии есть). И там он показывает и расход памяти и есть вкладочка Memory Usage, где есть кнопка Take Snapshort. Делаете снапшоты в нужные моменты и ковыряетесь в них.Делая несколько можно посмотреть разницу с предыдущим

Comment: @vitidev, спасибо, понял, значит я не в том инструменте искал

Comment: @vitidev гранд мерси, нашел утечку, оформите как ответ